# CodeIgniter load two controller functions in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a simple ToDo list in CodeIgniter as I just learn it.

I have a profile page which should show the user details + all the items he checked to do.

This is my view so far

```
<div class="profile_header">
        <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
        <h4><?php echo $user['name']; ?></h4>

</div>
```

This is my controller

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $query = $this->model_users->getUserInfo();
    $data['users'] = null;
    if($query){
        $data['users'] =  $query;
    }
    $this->load->view('profile/profile', $data);
}
```

And my model

```
  public function getUserInfo(){
    $user_email = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $user_email));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Now you can see that I select the user information from the user table and send it to the view using the index controller function. Now if I want to get all the `tasks` from `list_task` table and show it on page, I assume I have to write a new model function and call it in my controller in a new function like `getUserTasks` but how do I send them over to the view?

Comment: You're not using versions 2 and 3 of CodeIgniter at the same time.  Please do not tag-spam.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just add another element to your `$data` array.

So your controller would look something like this:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $query = $this->model_users->getUserInfo();
    $data['users'] = null;
    if($query){
        $data['users'] =  $query;
    }

    // Load tasks (create a new method in your model)
    $data['tasks'] = $this->model_users->getUserTasks();

    $this->load->view('profile/profile', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I strongly recommend you create 2 model which names are  users and tasks.

In user model, just write codes about the users and your users table.

```
<?php
    class User_model extends CI_Model {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function getUserInfo(){ /*Fetch your users data*/ }
    }
?>
```

In your task model, just write codes about the tasks and your tasks table.

```
<?php
    class Tasks_model extends CI_Model {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function getTasks($user){ /*Fetch tasks of user which specified by $user */ }
    }
?>
```

Finally, using these functions of 2 models, fill your all data in controller and send it to view.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->load->model('Tasks_model');

    $queryOfUsers = $this->user_model->getUserInfo();
    $queryOfTasks = $this->tasks_model->getTasks();

    //manage/edit your data comes from database as you did above.
    //put it in data and send to view.

    $this->load->view('profile/profile', $data);
}
```

Codeigniter and other frameworks exist for easy coding and debugging. If you combine all functions in a model, you can not trace them easily and end of the project, you will be very far from the Object Oriented.